# How to animate pseudo element like before and after in framer motion

Tags: reactjs, animation, pseudo-element, framer-motion

Is there any way to animate the pseudo elements of a react element, because I can't find any solutions anywhere

I have tried to wrap the pseudo elements as such

```js
const buttonVariants = {
  visible: {
    "&::before": {
      transform: "rotate(90deg)",
    },
  },
  hidden: {
    "&::before": {
      transform: "rotate(0)",
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).